# bootstrap tabs hides background image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site which uses bootstrap tabs/pills from w3 schools(http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs&stacked=h)
I wanted to show background for the entire web page but the content of the tabs always hide the background image.

```
html { 
         background: url("bground.jpg") no-repeat center fixed; 
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? see here: https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/16/

Comment: Can you show us your html. Also, do you have any custom styling on your tabs or content within your tabs?

Comment: Welcome! Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**Use body instead of html**

```
body{
    background: url("bground.jpg"); 
}
```